# MySQL Unknown column 'Price' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm getting an error when inserting data into a MySql database. I get this error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Price' in 'field list'

When using this command:

```
INSERT INTO CubePrice(Price, DateTime, ShopID, CubeID) VALUES ("99.99", "23.41.53 43:12:32", "1", "1")
```

I have a column named `Price` in the table `CubePrice`.
What am I doing wrong? Why do I get this error? I get the same error when trying to use the same query in C#. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like yout table has no column Price, can you Show the table description?

Comment: Please show the definition of your table... the error doesn't lie..

Comment: show your table and then check your date time entry. eg it should be like this '2016-08-18 15:42:19'

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/PIgOt

Comment: I have same experience.. but I make query withour `` mark the query can be executed

Answer (score 0):

You might check your choice of quotes (use double-/ single quotes for values, strings, etc and backticks for column-names).
Try using different quotes for Price value.

Comment: I put backticks for column names, but that just made it throw the same error. Single quotes gives the syntax error 'missing 'select''. Double quotes just throws a syntax error.

Comment: Than could you post screenshot or whatever of your table "CubePrice"?

Answer (score 0):

try this query to insert. if you have price field. this query will run

```
INSERT INTO CubePrice(Price, DateTime, ShopID, CubeID) VALUES (99.99, '2016-08-18 15:42:19', 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this kind of brackets  (“`”). Otherwise MySQL "thinks" that you point to a column named "99.99".
I tried it and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the answer is:

**CHECK YOUR COLUMN NAMES!!!**

I had a space or something somewhere in the price column name. Just retype the column name to check it.